# My computer doesn't wake up from suspend? And shows message Alarms can be upto a month in the future

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, power-management, 17.04

I have an ASUS R558UQ-DM701D Intel i7 7500U Processor 2.7G,3M Processor speed
8GB Memory RAM, 1 TB Hard Disk, NV GT 940MX 2G DDR3 with Ubuntu 17.04. Whenever my computer suspends and when I try to get it back it doesn't work.  [I just get this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G7eS.jpg) and it doesn't let me login back in, I have to force power off and then restart my computer.

---

I am looked all over for a solution and haven't found anything that has worked for me. [When I do `dmesg |grep rtc`
 I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3kaU.png)

---

I am currently using the Nvidia binary driver- 375.66 from Nvidia-375 (proprietary, tested)

---

I would really love to get a quick answer to this problem as I am new to the Linux community and ain't able to find a solution and this is killing the battery life and usability of my computer

Comment: How old is your computer? Could it be that your motherboard battery needs to be replaced?

Comment: My computer is brand new like got it this month so highly doubt that this problem